# Is it ok to write a note of the same register in two voices (SATB)?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-inversions, chord-voicings

I want to know if this is allowed when writing for SATB. The chord is *D/F#*. The note *D* is of the same register, but repeated in the Alto & Tenor voices. Is this allowed in a music theory exam?

[image]

Comment: Which syllabus are you getting music theory lessons and exams from? I suspect things are at least slightly different between RCM and Trinity, for example.

Comment: Pretty sure the term is "doubling", in this case doubling the root. Not sure about whether your theory exam allows it, so this is a comment.

Comment: @Dekkadeci It's for Trinity.

Answer (score 1):

This is allowed in classical harmony.  I don't see why it shouldn't be allowed in a music theory exam, assuming that the voice leading to and away from it is correct.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to clarify if rules were different for a music theory exam.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell you that, because there are no fixed rules for music theory exams, as far as I know.  But I can't imagine how someone would object to it.